# Firebase database ValueEventListener onDataChange not called in Android tablet emulator

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-emulator

I have a piece of code that connects a Firebase ValueEventListener to listen to Firebase database changes.

On a phone emulator, it works and I get the data stored in Firebase.

But when I test it in a tablet emulator, the event callback function is not being called.

Is there anything I need to do differently for phones and tablets? thank you

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final MainFragment mainFragment = new MainFragment();

    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.main_act_frag_container, mainFragment).commit();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              /* gets called in phone emulator but not tablet emulator */

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(listener);
}
```

Comment: Were the phone and tablet emulators created with the same system image?  Check that the tablet emulator system image includes Google Play services.

Comment: When you look at tablet the listed of emulated devices in the AVD Manager, the _Target_ description should contain _Google APIs_.

Comment: thanks for response. They were created with different images but both support Google APIs (both have Target: google_apis [Google APIs] (API level 25)) but phone is x86_64 and tablet is x86. As a test I created another tablet emulator with the same image as phone, still same. emulators tested: phone(Nexus5x), tablet(PixelC/Nexus10)

Comment: Add a log or println statement to `onCancelled()`. Maybe your security rules are set to require signed-in user and you are signed-in on phone emulator but not tablet.  Also check that the tablet emulator has a network connection.

Comment: thanks. not signing in on the tablet was the exact problem (forgot about changing the firebase authority for dev). If you would please write your comments as an answer, would be thankful to choose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Log` or `System.out.println` statement to `onCancelled()`. Maybe your security rules are set to require signed-in user and you are signed-in on the phone emulator but not the tablet. Also check that the tablet emulator has a network connection.